# Swift 4 Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service

Tags: swift, webview, wkwebview

I have problem when use **WKWebView**.
i tried to use link http and https.
i get this error each time
***Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service***
Info.plist contain App Transport Security Settings

```
view.addSubview(wkWebView)
wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

view.addConstraintsWith(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: wkWebView)
view.addConstraintsWith(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: wkWebView)

if let aRequest = request {
     wkWebView.load(aRequest)
}
```

Comment: @fabspro no one of that steps didn't help me